# What exceptions can be raised by `load_kube_config`?

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes

My team is using the Python3 kubernetes package in some of our code. What are the exceptions that can be raised by a call to `kubernetes.config.load_kube_config`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of the standard errors that can be raised at any point (MemoryError, OSError, KeyboardInterrupt, etc), it mostly uses its own ConfigException class. Just go read the code for yourself https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python-base/blob/master/config/kube_config.py